# Javascript confirm popup do nothing on cancel click

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, confirm

When using Javascript's Confirm functionality, the goal I am attempting to accomplish is to do nothing and to close the alert message that pops up when the cancel button is selected. However, as the below code works, when the user presses 'cancel' it still allows the page to submit the form and change pages. From what I looked up, it appears as though a return false would resolve the matter but it does not seem to be working in my case. Feedback and input appreciated.

ASP Code:

```
 <asp:Button ID="save" runat="server" OnClientClick="message();" Text="Save" />
```

JS Code:

```
function message() {
    var message= "";
    var message= confirm("Continue?");
    if (message == true) {   
        return message;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the method in the `OnClientClick`.

```
OnClientClick="return message()"
```

So you code would be as follows

```
<asp:Button ID="save" runat="server" OnClientClick="return message();" Text="Save" />
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it!